# how to htaccess pwd-protect a WP login?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have tried the instructions in this guide

http://titanfusion.net/how-to-protect-wp-login-php-using-htaccess-and-htpasswd/

I only got "error, webserver misconfigured" with that setup.

I also tried the following on the wp-admin directory (but even if below coda HAD worked, that wouldn't protect the actual login page, only the wp-admin sites behind the login form, I think.

in .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Required"
AuthUserFile /www/passwords/password.file
```

and then I used a web generator for the actual password-file so that should be ok.

Anyone know of a working guide how to set it up?

Comment: `/www/passwords` is likely not a directory

Answer (score 0):

If your .htaccess file is in the some folder like your password.file you can try this:

```
AuthUserFile password.file
```